# Why i cannot run my MVC5 app, error from web.config file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

In my MVC applications WebUI project's web.config file was modified with the following connectionStrings tags

```
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="EFDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=SportsStore;Integrated Security=True"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>

  <configSections>    
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
```

When hit F5 it gives me the following error page shown on the link below, can any one tell me why and how to fix this?

Note: Without connection string in `<connectionStrings>...</connectionStrings>` it works. but why is the error?

https://1drv.ms/a/s!AnpqTBe4ZZ2hbO7cMNILg4PTeBk

Answer (score 1):

Just as the error message says. You can only have 1 `configSections` element in your config file. Furthermore, it must be the **first** child element of `<configuration>` in the config file.

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>    
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>

    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="EFDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=SportsStore;Integrated Security=True"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/configsections-element-for-configuration):

> **Remarks**
>
> If this element is in a configuration file, it must be the first child element of the `<configuration>` element.

References:

- [`<configSections> element for <configuration>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/configsections-element-for-configuration)
- [Configuration File Schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/)

Comment: thanks solved my issue, so the very first line in the web.config must be <configSections> is there way to know the order of other elements in web.config file....?

Comment: @Mr.Tib - I have added links to the relevant documentation to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the links with articles : )

Answer (score 0):

```
  <configSections>    
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>

        <connectionStrings>
    <add name="EFDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=SportsStore;Integrated Security=True"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Swap `<connectiornStrings>` with `<confogSections>`

Error says you can have only one configSection attribute as well as it must be first in the config file.

Comment: i'm having difficulty with understanding what you have written but i believe you try to say swap <connectionstring> with <configsections> which was explained well by NightOwl888

Comment: Yeah swap, that was a typo.